# nodejs How to execute a mysql query with 2 statements

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'd like to execute 2 mysql statements with one query in node js. However this fails with the error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near

My node command and mysql query looks as follows.

```
connection.query( "UPDATE `table1` SET `count` = `count` + 1 WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1; INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `field1`, `datetime`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`) VALUES     (NULL, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, 'impression');", 
    [var1, var2, var3,var4],
    function(err, rows) {
        connection.release();
        if (err != null) {
            // Do error logging
            console.log(this.sql);
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Taking the mysql query statement from the console log and executing it manually works perfectly fine. Thus the problem must be caused by node mysql.

How can I execute these two statements with one query in node js?

Thx, i really appreciate your expertise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), support for multiple queries is disabled by default. To enable it, do it when creating your connection:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#multiple-statement-queries) for more information.